# Class methods and expect argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have simple test case: (board has_many links, link belongs_to board)

```
context "with feeds" do
  let (:board) {FactoryGirl.create(:board_tree)}

  it "returns links from all feeds" do
    expect(board.all_links.count).to eq Link.all.count
  end
end
```

It fails (`expected 8 got 2`) - which is ok, I expected the same.

Now I switch this expect with:

`expect(Link.all.count).to eq board.all_links.count`

This time I thought it will fail with `expected 2 got 8`, but instead of it I get: `expected 2, got 0`.

Any idea why? For me both expectations should be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try changing:

```
let (:board) {FactoryGirl.create(:board_tree)}
```

into

```
let! (:board) {FactoryGirl.create(:board_tree)}
```

you will see that the results won't change when you invert the conditions. The problem is that links are created by rspec the first time that the `board` variable is referenced, so in the second example, there are no links yet when rspec is evaluating the `expect(Link.all.count)` part.

Comment: Great, just realized that I read about it yesterday :). Thank you.